# re-using spring configuration properties in nested map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot application that supports multi-tenancy.  I wish to support global and per-tenant configuration of a bunch of custom configuration properties. For each property, a global value can be configured, but for a specific tenant the value may be overridden.

Currently I only have global properties, using some classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.
E.g.

```
    @ConfigurationProperties("props1")
    class Props1 {
        ...
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("props2")
    class Props2 {
        ...
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("props3")
    class Props3 {
        ...
    }
```

I'd like to be able to have properties configured like this:

```
props1.a=...
props1.b=...

props2.x=...
props2.y=...

props3.z=...

tenant.some-tenant-id.props1.b=...
tenant.some-tenant-id.props3.z=...

tenant.some-other-tenant-id.props2.x=...
```

I'm considering adding another `@ConfigurationProperties` class with e.g. prefix `tenant` and with for each of the existing classes a `Map`, where the key will be the tenant name, such as:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("tenant")
class TenantSpecificProps {
   private Map<String, Props1> props1;
   private Map<String, Props2> props2;
   private Map<String, Props3> props3;
   ...
}
```

However I'm concerned that reusing the classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` for the maps may lead to issues later on, since this is not the normal way these classes are used in Spring.  Also, I'll need to merge global and per-tenant values (per-tenant overriding global ones) manually.

Is this a valid approach, and/or is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear to me. Maybe it would be better to consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Can you explain what you want to achieve and what issues are you afraid of?

Comment: @Betlista I've edited the question, hopefully my intention is clearer now?

Comment: Why not run an instance per tenant and use SpringBoot profiles to load the "override" configuration?

Comment: you can use this kind of architecture -> https://reflectoring.io/flyway-spring-boot-multitenancy/

Comment: @Ralf That's what I'm doing now but as more tenants get added we want to save on resources by removing the 1-1 mapping of instance to tenant.

Comment: @SahinYanlık That article shows how to put tenant-specific configuration properties in a Map, I know how to do that.  As far as I can see it doesn't have global properties which can be overridden by tenant-specific values.